# How to obtain user accounts from groups within OU?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am trying to obtain all the user accounts from a particular Oraganizational Unit. I have the base dn, scope and filter as follows:

```
   BASEDN  "OU=dc users,DC=example,DC=com"
   SCOPE    SUBTREE_SCOPE
   FILTER   "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))"
```

The OU I am searching, consists of sub OU's as well as groups. The problem is I am able to obtain all the user accounts in the sub OU's but
Iam not able to obtain the user accounts in the groups within the OU. Any idea why?

EDIT:

Also if i search a group which consists of sub groups, Iam unable to obtain user accounts in the sub groups as well. Is it not possible to apply sub tree search for groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an LDAP directory server, entries have a type (based on the objectClass attribute). They are groups or users or organizational units... When you search, you are returned the entries that matches your filter. In your example, you are searching for entries of type users, not groups. You can change your filter to return both groups and users, but your code will need to parse the returned entries to detect the type and what to do with them.